# How can I undo/reverse an XOR with PHP?

Tags: php, xor

I'm a bit confused by `XOR`, conceptually. I have an light encryption function I need to decrypt, and I'm not sure how to get it working correctly.

If my value was originally generated by:

```
$val = dechex($seed^$id);
```

Then, elsewhere, I have the corresponding $val and $seed, how can I generate the $id?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

XOR is its own inverse, so you can just XOR `$val` by `$seed` again and get `$id`.  You might need to run `hexdec` on `$val` first, though.

Comment: Another fun XOR fact: xoring a value with itself makes it 0. Very handy trick on Intel processors when writing in assembler. `XOR EAX,EAX` actually compiles down to a single byte instruction, whereas `MOV EAX,0` takes up 6 bytes (I think, been a while since I've done assembler).

Comment: @Marc: I also believe, at least for recent AMD processors, that they know that `XOR EAX,EAX` doesn't use the old value of `EAX` and so doesn't require it to be computed.

Comment: Compute what? EAX is a register and is always available. There shouldn't be anything to compute.

Comment: @Marc: It won't wait for any previous instructions that write to `EAX` to complete.

Comment: Hopefully Athlons would remember that the in-flight computation's result needs to be ignored, in that case. Otherwise you'll end up with a non-zero EAX at some point after doing the XOR.